Could not resolve host: github.com within docker build process in WSL
Within a Dockerfile, I am trying to pull a public GitHub repository into the image. When building the image locally, the build process always fails at the git clone step:
15.20 Cloning into 'bats-core'...
20.22 fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/bats-core/bats-core.git/': Could not resolve host: github.com
------
Dockerfile:5
--------------------
   4 |     
   5 | >>> RUN apk add --update coreutils && \
   6 | >>>     apk add --update dos2unix && \
   7 | >>>     apk add --no-cache git && \
   8 | >>>     git clone --branch v1.2.1 https://github.com/bats-core/bats-core.git && \
   9 | >>>     ./bats-core/install.sh /usr/local && \
  10 | >>>     rm -rf bats-core
  11 |     
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c apk add --update coreutils &&     apk add --update dos2unix &&     apk add --no-cache git &&     git clone --branch v1.2.1 https://github.com/bats-core/bats-core.git &&     ./bats-core/install.sh /usr/local &&     rm -rf bats-core" did not complete successfully: exit code: 128

There is nothing wrong with the Dockerfile as my coworkers who aren't using WSL can build it fine, and one of my coworkers reproduced this error in WSL. I am also able to ping other websites within the build process, so the build does have access to internet connection. It's almost like a firewall setting is blocking github.com specifically, but I'm not sure. Here is the full Dockerfile
FROM gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk:408.0.0-alpine

USER root

RUN apk add --update coreutils && \
    apk add --update dos2unix && \
    apk add --no-cache git && \
    git clone --branch v1.2.1 https://github.com/bats-core/bats-core.git && \
    ./bats-core/install.sh /usr/local && \
    rm -rf bats-core

RUN gcloud components install gsutil && \
    mkdir -p files files_to_upload files_to_decrypt && \
    apk add file

ARG IMAGE_SHA

ENV IMAGE_SHA=$IMAGE_SHA

COPY /app /app

COPY /init /init

COPY /test /test

ENTRYPOINT ["bash"]

Here is my /etc/resolv.conf
# This file was automatically generated by WSL. To stop automatic generation of this file, add the following entry to /etc/wsl.conf:
# [network]
# generateResolvConf = false
nameserver 172.18.176.1

Output of docker info
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:    26.0.1
 Context:    default
 Debug Mode: false
 Plugins:
  buildx: Docker Buildx (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  v0.13.1
    Path:     /usr/libexec/docker/cli-plugins/docker-buildx
  compose: Docker Compose (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  v2.26.1
    Path:     /usr/libexec/docker/cli-plugins/docker-compose

Server:
 Containers: 33
  Running: 0
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 33
 Images: 48
 Server Version: 24.0.5
 Storage Driver: overlay2
  Backing Filesystem: extfs
  Supports d_type: true
  Using metacopy: false
  Native Overlay Diff: true
  userxattr: false
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
 Cgroup Version: 1
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Runtimes: io.containerd.runc.v2 runc
 Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version: 3dce8eb055cbb6872793272b4f20ed16117344f8
 runc version: 
 init version: de40ad0
 Security Options:
  seccomp
   Profile: builtin
 Kernel Version: 5.15.133.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2
 Operating System: Ubuntu Core 22
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: x86_64
 CPUs: 8
 Total Memory: 7.598GiB
 Name: OV-7410-76
 ID: e5c4bb27-4c53-464f-abf2-96a9b28f5815
 Docker Root Dir: /var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker
 Debug Mode: false
 Experimental: false
 Insecure Registries:
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false

WARNING: No blkio throttle.read_bps_device support

Output of docker network ls
NETWORK ID     NAME      DRIVER    SCOPE
3f5bee21d4f5   bridge    bridge    local
80929bb5500d   host      host      local
286890ebad51   none      null      local

I've tried upgrading docker and looking into network configuration, but I don't know too much. I'm not sure if I have to authenticate docker with github in some way? It's a public repository so anybody should be able to pull, and given that the error has to do with not being able to resolve the host name I don't think it's a permissions issue.
